# How to use chainer.links.BatchNormalization when loading pretrained parameter then evaluating validation dataset

Tags: batch-normalization, chainer

I use pretrained imagenet model to use ResNet101 and BN layer  to train another dataset.

After I trained over, How should I evaluate the model?? Should I don't set `chainer.using_config('train', False)`??

I found the evaluate accuracy is too low even I evaluate on the train dataset not (only achieve 80%) not validation dataset. But when I switch to `chainer.using_config('train', True)`, The accuracy get reach 99%.

I have also put the question on https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/4553

One of reviewer comments:

I think the problem is caused by that BatchNorm uses different statistics for training and testing.

My answer is based on the assumption that you are applying a pre-trained model on a new dataset (including training/validation/test set). Maybe I'm wrong

Specifically, if you use a pre-trained model, then the statistics of the batches in the original dataset (maybe ImageNet) is reused. As a result, during training, the statistics (mean, std) is actually the combination of the previous dataset and your current training split. Then if you evaluate the training split again with chainer.using_config('train', False), the statistics is reset and thus is purely from the training split. These differences may cause the performance degradation, as I have previously encountered.

Anyway, I think it's important to consider what data are used for computing the running average of statistics for BatchNorm, since this will make a big difference for evaluation even if using the same data.

Answer (score 0):

> Then if you evaluate the training split again with chainer.using_config('train', False), the statistics is reset and thus is purely from the training split.

I guess this understanding is wrong. As written in the [docstring of BarchNormalization](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/links/normalization/batch_normalization.py#L30-L33),

> ```
> In testing mode, it uses pre-computed population statistics to normalize
> the input variable. The population statistics is approximated if it is
> computed by training mode, or accurate if it is correctly computed by
> fine-tuning mode.
> ```

Thus, when you use `with chainer.using_config('train', False)` statement, the statistics learned at training time is used.
So the conclusion is you should use `with chainer.using_config('train', False)` during evaluation.

Note that in training mode,

> ```
> In training mode, it normalizes the input by *batch statistics*. It also
> maintains approximated population statistics by moving averages, which can
> be used for instant evaluation in testing mode.
> ```

Therefore, whole statistics **is not used**, instead **batch statistics** is used.

Comment: But My experiment result told me, When I use with chainer.using_config('train', False), the accuracy performance drops so much.

Comment: But How to evaluate? You still don't answer my question